# New tab in chromium is empty

Tags: chromium

I uninstalled some programs yesterday and it is possible I also changed/deleted some files/settings for Chromium browser. When I open new tab in Chromium, I only see blank page - no wallpaper, no shortcuts, no Google search field.

[image]

Is there any way to set new tab to this form?

[image]

I tried remove all directories for chromium that I found and reinstall it, but problem was not solved:

```
sudo snap remove --purge chromium

sudo find / -name chromium
sudo rm -r /etc/chromium
sudo rm -r /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/chromium
sudo rm -r /root/snap/chromium
sudo rm -r ~/snap/chromium

sudo snap install chromium
```

I also find [similar problem](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2376880), but it for Google Chrome, so I do not have this option to use in Chromium. When I install Google Chrome, new tab looks as it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set flag  `chrome://flags/#ntp-webui` (Use the WebUI new tab page when opening a new tab) to **Disabled**, and relaunch browser. Just checked on chromium **version 88.0.4324.96**

Comment: what ntp-webui actually does? Also thanks it helped

Comment: `WebUI` is just an alternative framework used for responsive `New Tab Page` design  @Panagiss