# Why do I get a black screen in Chromium?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, google-chrome, screen, chromium

So today when I entered in chromium I got a black screen. I mean, until now every time I entered in chromium the google search bar appeared with my shortcuts to some webpages, but today when I entered I got a black screen and I only can use the upper search bar, but the rest of the screen is just black, this is pretty weird because it''s the first time that has happened to me. Does anyone know why this happens? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New tab in chromium is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310344/new-tab-in-chromium-is-empty)

Comment: yes, it does, thank you so much! @Spatz

Comment: If this link answered your question please click the duplicate link in the blue banner above your question to confirmthat it is a duplicate question.